# How to integrate Google Map in MVC5 application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am following the [introduction of Google Map API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial) and want to integrate it in MVC of ASP.NET. I can initiate page start.html, and view elements of _Layout.cshtml, but Google Map does not show up. Could you help me fix this? Thank you!
In views/Start.html

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
} 

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Road Trip Agent";
} 
<h3>@ViewBag.Message</h3>
@Styles.Render("~/bundles/map")
<p></p> 

<div id="map"></div>
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")

<script>

var map;
function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
    zoom: 8
  });
}

</script>
<script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=I have put my key here&callback=initMap">
</script>

}
```

In App_Start/BundleConfig.cs: 
....

```
  bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/map").Include(
                    "~/Content/bootstrap.csss",
                    "~/Content/jquery-ui.css",
                    "~/Content/map.css"));
```

....

In Content/map.css:

```
html, body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
  #map { height: 100%; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use:

```
    <div id="map" style="width:800px; height:500px;"></div>
```

i.e. `px` instead of `%` it displays.